# Powerbuilder.net assemble not in DotNet web service (WCF)

Tags: wcf, powerbuilder

I have project in PB 12.5 and want to migrate on dotnet core. I found a shortcut to migrate my business logics from PB to .net core.
I build a dll in my pb.net project and use it in framework 4 dotnet WCf project. After adding dll and run my project it work fine but when i deploy my project on iis then it gives me error.
"Could not load file or assembly 'pbtonet_assembly' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
Please note : pbtonet_assembly -> is my PB dll add in WCF project as reference.
[image]

Comment: What is the DLL file you set up? However itself this kind of practice is not very desirable, for a long time.

Comment: Its work after installing pb.net runtime package